# Defining a XML entity without having the DTD "scheme"

Tags: xml, dtd, entities

I'd like to use XML entities to define text snippets shortcuts.
But for that, I need to define DTD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE ruleset [
    <!ENTITY useCli SYSTEM "Define this setting using JBoss CLI or the web console.">
]>
<ruleset id="..."
```

But this doesn't work since XML tools complain about the `ruleset` element not being defined. So I tried

```
    <!ELEMENT ruleset ANY>
```

But then it wants the child elements, attributes etc.

Is there a way to define a XML entity without defining the whole DTD? (There is a XSD schema for that document.)

Comment: You cannot define entities without a DTD. Some XML tools allow processing in non-validating mode where they expand entities without trying to validate the document.

Answer (score -1):

XSD is an alternative to DTD. If you have an XSD you shouldn't need a DTD.

See this answer for how to convert XSD to DTD: [Free XSD to DTD conversion utility?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45729820/free-xsd-to-dtd-conversion-utility)